# Prevent jquery from receiving .post() response or prevent php from returning response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, post

I am given the task to work on an https site with a jquery script which creates .post() requests to a friend site which isn't running on https of the moment.

Whenever my script hits the part where .post() is. Our site's https gets broken and in the console it says:

```
The page at https://www.Oursite.com/ displayed insecure content from http://www.FriendSite.com/Statistics.php.
```

Then I went to ask for the php script they have created to receive our data and the php doesn't even display anything. nor my jquery .post() is scripted to display anything.
Any ideas how I can solve this?

They will get https soon, but for now, it's disturbing to see the lock sign at chrome turn yellow.

How can I prevent a php script from not returning a response?
or fix jquery post to not receive any response?

Comment: comment out the offending code until https is supported

Comment: The problem is that you are posting the form to an non-SSL-site. It would be the same problem if you were trying to load an image from their site, you would get warnings for using non-secure content.

Comment: @Vector I can not do that. I'll still explain to our head though.

Comment: @NoLifeKing Thanks for replying. isn't there a temporary workaround for this? I want to know and try fixing this first before I report to head. Thanks! :)

Comment: probably overkill, but you could try to post the values to a page of your own and with PHP do a CURL request to the non-https site..

Comment: Isn't this an issue of "same origin policy"? Are you trying to retrieve data from a different domain with your .post()?

Comment: @Garytje Oh my LOL! That was easy, I didn't think of that. thanks! I will try using jquery to request to php on our site to friendsite. I have not tried this nor have used cURL, but will that work? Will cURL requests from a jquery requested php get processed?

Comment: @user2553780 Nope, Only sending statistics data and not expecting to receive anything.

And, the jquery script is fine, it send the data succefully, but gives the warning stated in this question.